# How I prevent touch screen from affects both qt application and desktop?

Tags: qt, raspberry-pi

I'm using raspberry pi 3B+ with Waveshare 5 inch Resistive Touch Screen LCD, HDMI.

I have created a simple desktop application using qt creator with a button on the middle of the screen. I have deployed the app to my raspberry pi and I can interact with it using the touch screen, everything works fine but when I press the button (or the screen at any point) is like I'm pressing the icons on desktop and when I close the app the desktop is full of applications and programs.

How I can prevent this?

Comment: What Linux distribution and desktop environment do you use on the Raspberry Pi?

Comment: I'm using "Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)" on a RPi 3 B+. Create the program using QT Creator on a Ubuntu 20.04.1 machine and cross compile for the pi. On RPi I have QT 5.12